# ASP.NET MVC images from a virtual Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I have an application that needs to get images that will not be part of the application it's self. But stored on the file System. I have been told the best way  to get this is to use a virtual directory rather than getting them staight off the file system like this

```
 public FilestreamResult GetPicture(string Filename) { 
    Filename = @"C:\SomePath\" + Filename;
        return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), "image/jpeg"));
}
```

Is it true using a virtual directory is the way to go instead of using the file path?
The next question is how do I create this virtual directory and how do I get the image from the virtual directory?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the method in your post has a bunch of overhead (all images pass through the .net application stack). If you plan on securing access to the images  or need some other application  level control then this can acceptable but if these are standard asset files then you will want to use a virtual directory.

You configure a virtual directory in IIS by right clicking the web site and selecting new virtual directory. You will give this directory a name such as "content" and then point it to your picture location (c:\somepath). You will then access the directory via http://yourwebsite.com/content/filename.jpg and it will appear as a part of your site.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Server.MapPath("~/someimage.jpg")`.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(VS.90).aspx

Comment: This will not help expose files that are not part of the web application itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what virtual directory means by you. But I don't think pulling files directly from File System is always a bad idea. It is simple and you don't have to worry about the Directory structure (which sometimes quite troublesome to 'simulate').

Since you mentioned asp.net, I would recommend you that instead of hardcoding the root of your storage, you can pull that out to `web.config` file.

Comment: Can you give an example of getting it out of the web.config? Thanks for the response